# lower bound for #numbers $n\leq x$, such that $2n+1$ and $2n-1$ aren't prime

Tags: number-theory

I'm searching for upper and lower bounds and a *good* estimate for the function $f$  ($f[x] \sim x$ for $x\to+\infty$), which is counting the numbers $n\leq x$, s.t. $2n+1$ and $2n-1$ aren't prime (OEIS A104278). I think with the help of the prime counting function this could be estimated quite precisely. e.g. $f(12)=0$, $f(13)=1$, $f(16)=1$, $f(17)=2$.